# Set size of matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I created two subplots on a MPL figure, but i'm having an hard time setting the size on them. I want  the space to be splitted between the two charts, so each chart needs to have 50% of the total width of the figure, and i want them to have the same height of the figure, here is how i initialized the subplots:

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=155, figsize=(10, 3))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,0), facecolor='#131722')
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5,3), (2,2), colspan=5, rowspan=4, facecolor='#131722')

Colors = [['#0400ff', '#FF0000'], ['#09ff00', '#ff8c00']]

    for x in List:

        Index = List.index(x)

        rate_buy = []
        total_buy = []
        rate_sell = []
        total_sell = []

        for y in x['data']['asks']:
            rate_sell.append(y[0])
            total_sell.append(y[1])

        for y in x['data']['bids']:
            rate_buy.append(y[0])
            total_buy.append(y[1])

        rBuys = pd.DataFrame({'buy': rate_buy})
        rSells = pd.DataFrame({'sell': rate_sell})
        tBuys = pd.DataFrame({'total': total_buy})
        tSells = pd.DataFrame({'total': total_sell})

        ax1.plot(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total, color=Colors[Index][0], linewidth=0.5, alpha=1, label='test')
        ax2.plot(rSells.sell, tSells.total, color=Colors[Index][1],alpha=0.5, linewidth=1, label=x['exchange'])

        ax1.fill_between(rBuys.buy, 0, tBuys.total, facecolor=Colors[Index][0], alpha=0.4)
        ax2.fill_between(rSells.sell, 0, tSells.total, facecolor=Colors[Index][1], alpha=0.4)
```

And this is what i'm getting:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried that, but the output seems to be the same

Comment: I updated my question!

Comment: Try `ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0))` and `ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,1))`

Comment: @DavidG looks much better now, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

use `plt.tight_layout()` before calling plt.show().